# How to write output file after all regexp match?

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have text file containing line starts with mmrk.

I want to extract all lines and write output.

I am trying following code. (I know this is not correct method, Just to show what I want.)

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0
Dim fso, MyFile, FileName, Text
dim oFile, strPath
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FileName = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\2.rtf"
strPath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\1.txt"
Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)
Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    Text = MyFile.ReadAll
Loop
Set regEx_ = new regExp
With regEx_
 .Global = True
 .MultiLine = True
 .IgnoreCase = True

 'Do some regex find and replace(works perfectly)

 .Pattern = "mmrk.*"
    If regEx_.Test(Text) Then
    Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strPath, 2, True, -1)
      oFile.Write Text
      oFile.Close
    End If
End With
MyFile.Close
```

**Edit**
I need to get lines from string.

I am currently first saving temp file from string and use Nefariis's answer to do the rest. Is there any direct method.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you would like to do... Here is how I am understanding the question... 1. You have a textfile 2. Some lines in the text file start with "mmrk." 3. You would like to save those lines into a seperate text file .... is that correct?

Comment: Correcto, so is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are easier ways of doing this that do not involve a regex.

In VBScript:

```
FileName = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\2.rtf"
strPath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\1.txt"

Set inFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(FileName)
Set outFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(strPath,True)

Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
    Dim line : line = inFile.Readline
    If inStr(line, "mmrk.") = 1 then outFile.writeLine(line)
Loop

inFile.Close
outFile.Close
```

In VB.Net

```
Dim inFile as String() = File.ReadAllLines("inFileName")
Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("OutFileName", True)

For Each line As String In inFile
    If line.StartsWith("mmrk.") Then sw.WriteLine(line)
Next

sw.Close()
```

This reads the file in, then goes through it looking for lines the start with "mmrk.", and saves the line into a seperate text file that you specifiy.

Comment: Alright give that a try, the syntax should be pretty close if not spot on.

Comment: Your VBScript would check one line, but write the next line. You need to assign the line read from the file to a variable if you want to use it multiple times. Also, it's better to use `Left(line, 5) = "mmrk."` instead of `InStr`.

Comment: I see what you are saying -- but inSTR() works just fine for this example. It reads from the start of the string and looks for the string specified

Comment: `InStr` will work (I didn't say that it won't), but I consider `Left` easier to understand. When using `InStr` you need to be aware of the fact that it returns the position of the match in the string and you need to build your condition according to that.

Comment: thank you for the edit - vbscript is definitely not my first language.

Comment: mmrk.(dot) should be mmrk. Thanks. I asked for regex so that this can be broad answer. Anyway It has solved my problem. Tested for test file. Should work ok with the rest. will test and tell.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Totally agree. For me `If Left(line, 4) = "mmrk"` is more suitable.

Comment: @Nefariis: Sorry for not making it clear. Actually I get file as string. How to perform your code if it is a string.

Comment: @Rahul - You mean like this? Just edited the answer.

Comment: I made mistake in asking in first place. I get file content as string like `strtxt = replace(strtxt, "something","mmrk$something"`. I will accept this answer as you have answered the way I asked. I will ask separate question for What I want as it will be inappropriate to modify the original question.