# How to extract lines from String

Tags: vbscript

I am getting Thing done using this code.

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0
Dim fso, FileName, TextLine, Tempfile, inTempfile, strPath, Temp, intemp
FileName = "C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\PLR\1.rtf"
TempFile = "C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\PLR\Temp\1.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set inFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName)
Do While inFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    TextLine = inFile.ReadAll
Loop
Set regEx_ = new regExp
With regEx_
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "\{\\\w{4}\\\w{4}\\\w{11}"
TextLine = regEx_.replace(TextLine, "mmrk$&")
'many such find and replace to get IMP lines Having mmrk
End with
set Temp = fso.CreateTextFile(TempFile, True)
    Temp.Write TextLine
    Temp.Close
Set Temp = Nothing

Set intemp = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\PLR\Temp\1.txt")
Set outFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\PLR\Temp\11.txt",True)

Do Until intemp.AtEndOfStream
    Dim line : line = intemp.Readline
    If Left(line, 4) = "mmrk" then outFile.writeLine(line)
Loop

intemp.Close
outFile.Close
inFile.Close
```

This works ok.
I have feeling that this is not right. How to make this code right.

**The problem is**

If you see the code, You will notice that I am saving the string first as file and opening the same for reading again.
Is there anyway we can extract lines containing specific string from string so as to avoid it saving.

**Edit 2**

Let me narrow down the problem in step where I am getting mistake.

Step 1. Open the file for reading and get the text as string. Working OK

Step 2. Multiple Regex Find and replace in string. Working OK

**Step 3.   Extract lines from string having Left(line, 4) = "mmrk" to get desired lines as string. Not working**

Step 4. Further Process lines to get final string containing desired lines.- will work if step 3 works. (It actually working for hypothetical example)

Step 5. Write string to file. Will work if step 3 works (working for hypothetical example

How to do that from file is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137157/how-to-write-output-file-after-all-regexp-match).

Comment: See the `split` command. It can split a string into an array of strings broken on any character including Chr(13). `Filter` can make an array on a search string from another. See VBS Help (https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, if you have want to extract particular lines from an input file, replace something in them, and write the resulting (modified) lines to an output file, you'd simply do something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Pattern    = "^\{\\\w{4}\\\w{4}\\\w{11}"

Set inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\input.txt")
Set outFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\path\to\output.txt", True)
Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
    line = inFile.ReadLine
    If re.Test(line) Then outFile.WriteLine re.Replace(line, "mmrk$&")
Loop
inFile.Close
outFile.Close
```

If you have multiple patterns that you want to prepend with "mmrk" you'd use an alternation (several patterns separated by pipe characters):

```
^pattern|pattern|pattern|...
```

The `^` anchors the expression at the beginning of the string/line.

Comment: I have problem of not explaining the question properly. This is not the exact answer I wanted but I think I got an Idea from you answer. Will edit it the way I wanted.

Comment: I want to find in string not the file. Is it possible to read string as file. If this is possible using vbscript, will solve my problem. Searching for That.

Comment: @Rahul I have no idea what you're trying to tell me. You may want to add an example to your question showing sample input and what you expect the output to look like (demonstrating what should and what should not be in the output).

Comment: I tried Editing the question. Please review if it's clear to you now.

Comment: @Rahul The code I posted prepends lines matching the given pattern with "mmrk" and writes them to the output file. What doesn't work about that? Further replacements need to be added as appropriate, of course, but that's immaterial for the question you posted. Like I said, you need to show sample input and the output you expect from that input.

Comment: I can not explain it more. It's just simple. I just want to do `Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream` with string and not the file. Everything Just works fine but matching from every line from string is looks impossible. I think I should try Jscript for that.

Comment: @Rahul I proposed a solution for what you just described. Unless you can explain what the proposed solution fails to do or at least provide sample input and output (which I asked for twice), I cannot help you. And I seriously doubt that changing the language would improve anything.

Answer (score 1):

You use `readline` and `Instr()`.

Your code is for extreme problems.

Here's me using your technique to filter lines so it can handle difficult cases.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
    'Remove ^ from quoting command line. Quote, ampersand and brackets
    Pttn = Replace(Arg(2), "^(", "(")
    Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^)", ")")
    Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^&", "&")
    Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^""", """")
    Set regEx1 = New RegExp
    If Instr(LCase(Arg(1)), "i") > 0 then
        regEx1.IgnoreCase = True
    Else
        regEx1.IgnoreCase = False
    End If 
    If Instr(LCase(Arg(1)), "v") > 0 then
        IncExc = False
    Else
        IncExc = True
    End If 
    regEx1.Global = False
    regEx1.Pattern = Pttn 
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Line=Inp.readline
        If RegEx1.Test(Line) = IncExc then
            outp.writeline Line
        End If
    Loop
```

Filter reads and writes standard in and standard out only. These are only available in a command prompt.

```
filter <inputfile >outputfile
filter <inputfile | other_command
other_command | filter >outputfile
other_command | filter | other_command
```

Filter

```
filter filter {[i][v]|n} expression
filter filt {[i][v]|n} expression
```

Filters lines in a file by a regular expression. It is more flexible than Windows' Findstr.

Ampersands and brackets in expression must be escaped with the caret. Do not escape carets. Use hexidecimal code \x22 for quotes.

SearchOptions

```
i - ignore case
v - include non-matching lines
n - none
```

Expression

Regular Expression Reference

Example

To extract all section headers, ie, lines without an equal sign

```
filter filter iv "=" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

To extract all section headers starting with a lower case letter

```
filter filter n "\[[a-z].+" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

This shows the caret escaping an opening bracket for CMD.EXE and the backslash escaping the opening bracket for the RegEx engine

filter filter n "\^(" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"

This shows searching for a quote character

```
filter filter n "\x22" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

Comment: I will definately try this. Sorry for not making it clear. I have edited the question. The regex is working fine. I just want to find string withing string. That is the real problem. May be my understanding is wrong. I will try the direction you described.